# How to handle click event of button using add handler,remove handler

Tags: vb.net

I have go through Google,and different sites,to get the answer of add handler,remove handler.
As per Documentation on Msdn,to handle an event that fired on different scenario,we use AddHandle to link  methods with click event.(may i got it wrong way).
LET i have a Button Click Event,i want to link it with a method,

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
```

and method is

```
Sub EventHandler()
        ' Handle the event.
        MsgBox("EventHandler caught event.")
    End Sub
```

how can i handle them when both above are in same class,or in different class.
can i do this.

```
 AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler()
RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler()
```

,please guide me in proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event can be subscribed in two ways:

1. direct handling (when your control, a button in your example, is declared as WithEvents), and it will be triggered always:

   ```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      ' Some action
   End Sub
   ```
2. dynamically subscribe/unsubscribe events, for example:

   ```
   Sub test()

     ' Subscribe the handlers based on some criteria
     If True Then
         AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler1
     Else
         AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler2
     End If

   End Sub


   Sub EventHandler1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     ' some action

     ' if you wish to unsubscribe the event, do below
     RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler1

   End Sub

   Sub EventHandler2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

     ' some other action

     ' if you wish to unsbuscribe:
     RemoveHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf EventHandler2

   End Sub
   ```

Note:

1. you can subscribe to the event to multiple handlers
2. your handler have to match the signature of `Handler(Sender as object, e as EventArgs)`

Comment: how can i register control,with method